# Gives different meaning in another scope

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here i have a part of the code.in here i got the error.

ERROR >>A local variable named 'msg' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'msg', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

but i use all the thing inside SMSHelper class.then what is the another scope

```
public class SMSHelper
{
    private string msg;
    private string convertToISOfromUtf8(String msg, String to, String from)
    {

        String iso_msg = null;
        if (from.Equals("UTF-8"))
        {
            System.Text.Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            System.Text.Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

            byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(msg);
            byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
            String msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

The three lines marked with `<-- this` below each represent a declaration of a separate variable, each having the same name `msg`. Thus they conflict with eachother.

```
private string msg; // <-- this
private string convertToISOfromUtf8(String msg // <-- this
{
    // ...
    if (from.Equals("UTF-8"))
    {
        // ...
        String msg // <-- and this
    }
}
```

The following would work:

```
private string _msg;
private string convertToISOfromUtf8(String msg, // ...
{
    // ...
    if (from.Equals("UTF-8"))
    {
        // ...
        _msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: NB The class variable and method parameter don't conflict with each other. You could remove the underscore in your suggested fix, then you'd have to use `this.msg` in the method.

Comment: when i use underscores.. _msg then there's no error.but i wanted to know is that a good method or is there any problem ?

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe there is no problem. An underscore in a variable is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 4):

You have a parameter called `msg` - your local variable cannot have the same name.  You also have the class level variable with the same name - you can keep this as long as you access it with `this.msg`.

I suspect you didn't want to declare a new variable on your last line:

```
String msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

The 3 variables called `msg` are shown here:

```
public class SMSHelper
{
private string msg;     // <-- #1
private string convertToISOfromUtf8(String msg /* <-- #2 */, String to, String from)
{

    String iso_msg = null;
    if (from.Equals("UTF-8"))
    {
        System.Text.Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        System.Text.Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(msg);
        byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
        String msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);    // <-- #3
    }
```

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe: The function has a parameter named `msg`. Inside the body of the function you declare a variable named `msg`. The compiler does not accept this ambiguity.

Comment: whichone is ambiguity to compiler ?

Comment: #3 in my answer above.  This clashes with #2.

Comment: is there any solution for that ? newbie getting trouble here

Comment: The line with #3 is wrong.  If you intended to set the class-level variable, you can change it from `String msg =` to `this.msg =`

Comment: i got an error error is  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 1):

[Local variable declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (Section 8.5.1 of the C# specification)

From section 8.5.1:

> The scope of a local variable declared in a *local-variable-declaration* is the block in which the declaration occurs. It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the local-variable-declarator of the local variable. Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local variable or constant with the same name

---

you have declare the variable with smae name in the method declaration..

now in method you are declaring the parameter again by doing

```
String msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

causing the problem.

this also gives smae error

```
    private string msg;

    public void test(String msg)
    {
        msg = null;
        string msg = "abc";
    }
```

here same varible is declared three time but the actuall problem is cause by the third declaration of the same variable which is in same scope that you can see in sepcification link

Second declaration just hide the class level variable with the same name. its not cause any error ..

Comment: It's not an error to do this. The error is caused by the third declaration.